# Import products in magento through xml file

Tags: xml, wordpress, magento, import

Any best way to import products in magento through xml.
I have two websites one in wordpress and one in Magento. I want to import my wordpress products into magento, any way to import it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can you the inbuilt IMPORT / EXPORT  which you can find under SYSTEM > Import/Export.

Easiest way is to first export you products using the DATAFLOW PROFILES option , choose the Export All Products option. This will create a CVS file under /var on your server. Get that file , by ftp or what ever way you can access your server, and use it as a template - delete any products in there, delete any columns that you will not be using. Enter all the data row by row into this and save (make you leave the row headers of the data you are using. Some will be required such as SKU, Name , Description, Price,  etc - you should experiment a bit importing just one or two sample until you get a template that works for you.

To import , you can just go to Import or you can also use the data profiles option for imports aswell.

Certain things like custom options and images are very difficult (or impossible) to import) so you will have to do manaully